# How to 'show your work' with game theoretic notation

Tags: notation, game-theory

Everything I've read on game theory seems to describe the game in notation and solves it in natural language.

1. How do you work with notation in game theory?
2. Could you recommend a straight-forward introductory book to working with game theoretic notation.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us some of your background? Are you a maths major? what year?

Comment: Philosophy undergraduate. I know elementary set theory and predicate logic. I know the concepts you'd learn in an introductory game theory course, and use them regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yale has online materials for its Game Theory course, which are probably going to be useful. Here is the link: http://oyc.yale.edu/economics/econ-159

A lot of game theory notation is vector notation. You use vectors to denote strategies, as well as payoffs. Combinatorial games utilize graph theoretic and combinatorial notations. You will also find probability and statistics to be used in many games, and so familiarity with such notation will be useful.

Game Theory is really a diverse field, stretching into math, economics, and computer science. So a lot of the notation really depends on the field in which the game falls.

Comment: So, up to what level of calculus will I need to learn to be able to notate most of the concepts taught in introductions to game theory?

Comment: Game Theory, and Economics in general, utilizes partial derivatives a lot. These show up in a multivariable calculus course. Much of economics revolves around optimization, so you need multivariable calculus to really keep up. Statistics will be useful as well. This should be plenty to get you going. If you want to get into game theory at a graduate level, I would strongly encourage at least a junior level course in real analysis (perhaps called advanced calculus at your school).